# Open Cart Multi Store Url Issue after transferring to another domain

Tags: url, opencart, store, server.transfer

Demo Domain: http://saltwater.codiixx.com/

Main Domain: http://thesaltwaterjunkies.com/

I am a front end developer i customized an opencart theme on our demo server.

but after transferring it to main domain.

its second store still showing our demo server url on links.

Main domain is working fine but its multi store showing this error.

Comment: I couldn't find any problem in home page. Can you please let us know the areas where the issue can be found?

Comment: at top of the header there is a link coral and fish. links inside coral and fish redirects to same url both the sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your links appear fine for me.

I would advice though to check the admin settings and update your store URL and store settings as even the Your Store message appears

```
Admin > System > Settings > [Edit] Your Store
```

Comment: You mean `Admin > System > Settings > [Edit] Your Store`? I have OC 1.5.6.4 and I don't see a `Stores` link in the menu

Comment: @tttony Yes I sent on the move. +1